# Javascript function does not work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

```
$("#search-btn-duplicate").click(function(event) {
    $(".search-container .dropdown-menu li").remove();
    $(".search-container .dropdown-menu").append('<li class="loading"><i class="icon-refresh icon-refresh-animate"></i></li>');

   var searchFieldDuplicateContent = $("#search-field-duplicate").val();
   var firstProtocol = $("#protocol").text();
   firstProtocol = firstProtocol.replace(/\s/g, '');

   if (searchFieldDuplicateContent != null){
       if (searchFieldDuplicateContent.length > 2){
           ajaxSearchFieldDuplicateContent(searchFieldDuplicateContent, firstProtocol);
        }
    }
});

function ajaxSearchFieldDuplicateContent(searchFieldDuplicateContent, firstProtocol){
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/requests/search_for_duplicate',
    data: {
        protocol: searchFieldDuplicateContent,
        first_protocol: firstProtocol
    },
    success: function(data) {
        id = data.substring(0, data.indexOf("_"));
        bindId = data.substring(data.indexOf("|")+1);
        data = data.substring(data.indexOf("_")+1, data.indexOf("|"));
        $(".search-container .dropdown-menu li").remove();
        if (data.length > 0){
            $(".search-container .dropdown-menu").append('<li><a><span id="protocol_to_bind" style="cursor: pointer;" class="span11">'+data+'</span></a></li>');
            $("#protocol_to_bind").click(function(){
                $("#search-field-duplicate").val(data);
                $(".button-submit").click(function(){
                    ajaxRequestBind(bindId);
                });
            });
        }else {
            $(".search-container .dropdown-menu").append('<li><a href="#" > Nenhum Resultado</a></li>');
        }
    }
});
}

function ajaxRequestBind(bindId){
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/requests/bind/' + id,
    data: {
        bind_id: bindId
    },
});
window.location.href = window.location.href + '?refresh';
}
```

**This function works perfectly on Chrome** but does not work on Firefox. I thought it could be a bootstrap problem with the dropdown, but could not fix it anyway. Also, Firefox keeps printing a warning on console for every click anywhere on the page. `Empty string passed to getElementById().`

```
var searchFieldDuplicateInput = document.getElementById('search-field-duplicate');
searchFieldDuplicateInput.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        $("#search-btn-duplicate").click();
    }
});
```

There is also a weird behavior, when I press Enter for the first time to do the search it does not work and the same warning `Empty string passed to getElementById().` is printed to the console, but then again when I press for the second time, it does work. The warning keeps showing even if I comment this code out. This is the only place `getElementById()` is used on my code.

The warning points to that file `http://localhost:3000/assets/application.self-5bb11bb64996b58cc9fe309d67b3587d80bbfbb0a0537f7773feae2c6cc4f207.js?body=1` on that line `elem = document.getElementById( match[ 2 ] );`

Besides that, everything goes as expected but this part is not working `ajaxRequestBind(bindId);`. The page is refreshed but the rails method does not work.

---

I made it work with `setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = window.location.href + '?refresh'; }, 2000);` Had to wait 2 seconds to refresh the page. If I refresh the page instantly after the ajax it doesn't work. Don't know why this happens. But I still have issues with that weird behavior with that warning popping up.

Comment: can you put a little demo?

Comment: which line throws error? what is working? what is not working?what is your desired output? Complete your question.

Comment: Sounds like you have a JS error somewhere else in the page.  You're not even using getElementById in this script.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with *substantially* less code?  Have a read of [mcve].  ie, is it caused by the $.ajax?  Most likely not, most likely by the success callback - so does it still occur if you take out the ajax and just include the success code?  if so, take the ajax part out of the question.

Comment: There is no error. The warning keeps showing on every click. Its just a search input that appends the search result on a dropdown item.

Comment: Can you copy and add the warning to the question.

Comment: `Empty string passed to getElementById()`. That's the warning, it's on the question

Comment: Like @RaajNadar already mentioned: Please specify "does not work on Firefox", clarify what **exactly** is not working as expected.

Comment: Code works even after you commented it. You should clear your cache and then try again.

Comment: Just realized that if I take this line out `window.location.href = window.location.href + '?refresh';` and refresh manually after, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work on Firefox with `setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = window.location.href + '?refresh'; }, 2000);` Had to wait 2 seconds to refresh the page. If I refresh the page instantly after the ajax it doesn't work. Don't know why this happens. I think this is more a workaround than a solution. But I still have issues with that weird behavior with that warning popping up.